# UIWebView resource handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Can I get a `UIWebView` to query my custom function to get `NSData*` for any resource it needs loaded?

The `UIWebViewDelegate` function `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` doesn't get triggered for every resource being loaded, such as CSS for example.

What I need is a function (that I have control over) that gets called every time a resource is requested. In my wxWidgets application, I make use of the wxWebViewHandler class and its GetFile method.

Comment: I am currently looking into `NSURLProtocol ` to see how far I get.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help for you

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:   (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {

   // here deside whether you go futher or not accoding to return yes      or no 

    return NO;

        }

return YES;
```

}

Comment: As I've described in my question, this function does not get triggered for resources such as CSS, so this is not a solution.

Comment: are you getting any solution for this